# Implementing an AJAX Request with Django, SQL, JavaScript, and React

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, django, ajax

I am currently building a website using Django and React, and I am currently facing a challenge. I want to make an AJAX request to retrieve data from the server and dynamically update it using JavaScript on the client side.

For this purpose, I am using Django to provide an API and SQL for data modeling. On the client side, I am using React to create a dynamic user interface.

So far, I have been able to establish the connection between Django and React and successfully transfer data from the server to the user. However, I now want to dynamically fetch and update the data through an AJAX request, so that when the information changes on the server side, it is automatically displayed on the page.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Created an API using Django and Django Rest Framework to provide the data.
Created a React component to display and update the data using `useState` and `useEffect`.
Used the Axios library on the client side to send AJAX requests.
Here is some sample code I have written:

On the server side:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/data/', views.data_api, name='data-api'),
]

# views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def data_api(request):
    data = {
        'name': 'John',
        'age': 25,
        # ...
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

On the client side:

```
// DataComponent.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const DataComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/data/');
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        <div>
          <h2>{data.name}</h2>
          <p>Age: {data.age}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataComponent;
```

So far, I have been able to retrieve initial data from the server and display it in the React component. However, I am unsure how to dynamically fetch and update the data on the page using an AJAX request. Additionally, should I consider any potential conflicts with other page functionalities?

Any guidance on how to dynamically fetch and update the data using an AJAX request would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into doing websockets and using a cache, that is usually how
these things are done.

**This is my Understanding of it**
The big problem is the server cant initiate a connection to the client to say: hey,
here's the new data; So the client has to initiate it with a *ping*

To make this *real time* the client is going to *ping* the server every 10-15 seconds and
ask if there's been an update. Now you *can* do this with AJAX requests on a timer, but
that would just be emulating a websocket and so that's probably not the best path

As for the cache, you **really** don't want to be hitting the database every 10-15
seconds to ask 'is there anything yet?'Instead you'd use a cache and look there for
any updates, much quicker. When a form is submitted you'd place the new data in the cache
and during the next *ping* the client will get it.

Hopefully you get the general gist. I'm haven't used react a lot so I can't provide a
code example, I think it might just be normal Javascript because this is all client side
code. All the pieces are generally here tho

---

I don't think there's anything wrong with starting with an AJAX POST on a timer to start
out with. In the front end I believe you'd just use normal Javascript to update the
values based on a class or id, be it changing the inner html of the `h3` or recreating
the entire parent div

```js
// update innerHTML example
// hit after: fetch, was successful, has `was_updated` flag in returned dict
document.getElementById('data_name_h2').innerHTML = data.name
```